# bootstrap column not responsive and too long after word-wrap

Tags: bootstrap-4, word-wrap, bootstrap-grid

Bootstrap columns aren't being responsive after implementing a word-wrap: break-word;

I am using bootstrap cdns.

I implemented it to stop it from the description text overflowing out of the column but there is a lot of extra white space. Taking the description text out results in  the column being responsive.

> ```
> <div class="row">
>     <div class="col-md-9 theborder stopoverflow">
>         Description:
>      {{event.description | safe}}
>     </div>
> ```

Here is my css:

> ```
> .stopoverflow {
>     word-wrap: break-word;
> }
> ```

[Image of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qN3md.png)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: use word-break instead of word-wrap

Comment: Hi Ramlal, I'm changed it to word-break: break-word; and it still isnt' working. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: word-break:break-all

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure why it's still not working :(

Comment: it depends on the space you given between the letters/words.Check as per your requirement

Answer (score 1):

use 'word-break:break-all;' instead of 'word-wrap:break-word'

> word-break: break-all
>       Irrespective of whether it’s a continuous word or many words, break-all breaks them up at the edge of the width limit even within the characters of the same word
>
> word-wrap: break-word 
>       This will wrap long words onto the next line.
>       break-word adjusts different words so that they do not break in the middle.

Check for detail info:
https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#overflow-wrap-property

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid ;
   width: 300px;
}

span {
  background-color: gray;
}

.break-all {
  word-break:break-all;
 }
.break-word {
  word-wrap:break-word;  
}
```

```html
<b>word-break:break-all</b>
<div class="break-all">
 DASDSD <span>ASDASDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
  </span> 
</div>
<br>
<b> word-wrap:break-word</b>

<div class="break-word">
  DASDSD <span>ASDASDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
  </span> 
</div>
```